# Separation Hahn Banach theorem in vector Banach lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-lattices

Let $X$ be  a vector Banach lattice. Let $C$ be a closed cone of positive elements in $X^+$ and let $0\leq x\in X-C$.

Q: Does there exists any bounded positive linear functional $f$ on $X$ by which $x$ and $C$ is separated?

Comment: Just to be clear: $X^+ = \{x \in X : X \ge 0\}$ and $C \subset X^+$? Is $C$ closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Try
\begin{align}
X &= \mathbb{R}^2, \\
X^+ &= \{x \in X : x_1, x_2 \ge 0 \},\\
C &= \{(t,t) : t \ge 0 \}, \\
x &= (1,0).
\end{align}

Comment: Nice and thanks.

Comment: Probably, there are some special closed convex subsets on which this version of Hahn-Banach theorem  holds. I  searched but nothing found. Could you please inform me any thing concerning this subject. \